# How do I use SQL variables to populate an HTML Table Row in APEX 5.0

Tags: html, sql, oracle-apex

So, the question is in the title. I have a select statement that produces my variables. This works fine as I have tested it in ever possible way I can think of. I also have an html email body that works. However, where things get lost in translation is when I try to show my variables in the HTML body. All the table cell shows is &v_pidm, &v_name and so on.

Here is the declaration statement:

```
declare
  subj varchar2(255) := 'Course Withdrawal Request - Complete';
  to_ varchar2(255) := 'someone@somewhere.edu'; 
  cc_ varchar2(255):= 'someone@somewhere.edu';
 from_ varchar2(255) := V('APP_USER')||'@somewhere.edu';
 body varchar2(32767);
 style varchar2(500);
 v_pidm number;
 v_name varchar(255) := 'stu_name';
 v_subj varchar(255); 
 v_crse varchar(255); 
 v_crn varchar(255); 
 v_title varchar(255); 
 v_term varchar(255); 
 v_status varchar(255);  
 v_comment  varchar(255);

begin
```

Here is the select statement:

```
Select distinct(ZSARWST_PIDM)
       ,spriden_first_name||' '||spriden_last_name stu_name
      , zsrrwct_subj
      , zsrrwct_crse
      , zsrrwct_crn
      , nvl(ssbsect_crse_title,scbcrse_title) title
      , zsrrwct_term
      , zsrrwct_crse_stat_ind
      , zsrrwct_comment
into v_pidm, v_name, v_subj, v_crse, v_crn, v_title, v_term, v_status, v_comment        
from ZRESWITHDRAW.zsrrwct

join zreswithdraw.zsarwst on zsarwst_id = zsrrwct_rwst_id 
join spriden on spriden_pidm = ZSARWST_PIDM           
join ssbsect on ssbsect_term_code = zsrrwct_term
            and ssbsect_crn = zsrrwct_crn
            --and ssbsect_ptrm_code = sobptrm_ptrm_code
            and ssbsect_subj_code = zsrrwct_subj
            and ssbsect_crse_numb = zsrrwct_crse
left join scbcrse on scbcrse_subj_code||scbcrse_crse_numb = ssbsect_subj_code||ssbsect_crse_numb
                 and scbcrse_eff_term = (select max(j.scbcrse_eff_term)
                                               from scbcrse j
                                              where j.scbcrse_subj_code||j.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code||scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb
                                                and j.scbcrse_eff_term <= zsrrwct_term)

where spriden_change_ind is null
  and zsrrwct_rwst_id = :P5_zsarwst_id;
```

I cannot share all of the HTML as some of it is brand specific, but here is the html that is specific to what I am trying to do:

```
<style>
.demo {
 border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 padding:10px;
}
.demo th {
 border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
 padding:10px;
 background:#F0F0F0;
}
.demo td {
 border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
 padding:10px;
}
</style>
<table class="demo" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   &v_pidm, &v_name, &v_subj, v_crse, v_crn, v_title, v_term, v_status, v_comment 
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

When this produces results, which it does, the table row simply reads:

&v_pidm, &v_name, &v_subj, v_crse, v_crn, v_title, v_term, v_status, v_comment

exactly like that with no actual variables.

If there is more information that would come in handy, please let me know and I will provide what I can. PHP is not an option unless it is the only option.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you using the HTML from your example? In the `p_body_html` of a `APEX_MAIL` procedure?

Comment: We are using it in a PL/SQL function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have concatenate your HTML string with the variables from your select. Something like this:

```
    declare

    some_variable varchar2(2000);
    html varchar2(4000);

    begin

    select 'something' into some_variable from dual;

    html:='<table class="demo" align="center">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  '||some_variable||'
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>';

    end;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but if you can try to use the incorporated apex functionalities like Interactive Report or Classic Report because they bring more performance and security. Good luck.

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately, we have no training here for APEX, so we are left to learn on our own. And doing the Hands on Labs aren't an option since the DBAs restrict what we have access to. I will definitely keep learning, though.

Comment: I suggest this you start [here](http://apex.oracle.com) were you have free access to apex and [OLL](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:2:::NO::P2_GROUP_ID,P2_PRODUCT_ID:1000,2039) for tutorials